# How to ensure Excel will close when all outstanding references are gone

Tags: excel, automation, com, out-of-process

My application launches and automates Excel:

```
Guid CLSID_ExcelApplication = ClsidFromProgID("Excel.Application");
Application xl = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ExcelApplication);
```

And now we're off to the races:

```
Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
ws.Name = "Monthly Expense Report";
```

And then normally you can [`.Quit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.quit) Excel:

```
xl.Quit();
```

And Excel goes away.

### Enter UserControl

What is **supposed** to happen is that if i had the code:

```
Application xl = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ExcelApplication);
xl.UserControl = false;
Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
ws.Name = "Monthly Expense Report";
ws = null;
wb = null;
xl = null;
```

Then Excel is supposed to automatically close when the last outstanding reference is gone. From MSDN:

> ## Application.UserControl property (Excel)
>
> When the UserControl property is **False** for an object, that object is released when the last programmatic reference to the object is released. If this property is **False**, Microsoft Excel quits when the last object in the session is released.

I'll just draw attention to that important line in the documentation above:

> ## **Microsoft Excel quits when the last object in the session is released**

When `.UserControl` is false, Excel is supposed to automatically terminate.

The `.UserControl` property defaults to **false**. But even if i force it to **false**, the out-of-process Excel automation object does **not** quit when the last object in the session is released:

[image]

## Crashing better

This becomes a problem if there is an unexpected exception while automating. Normally in order to get rid of Excel nicely you would:

- Make it visible, and let the user close it:

  ```
  xl.Visible = true;
  xl.UserControl = true; //prevent Excel from terminating when we null our reference below
  xl = null
  ```
- or call `.Quit` to quit:

  ```
  xl.Quit();
  xl = null;
  ```

Except if there is a catastrophic problem, i don't get a chance to call `.Quit` or call `.Visible = true`. And in these cases Excel is hanging around. Over days, weeks, and months it can sometimes mean literally dozen of them.

What can i do to ensure that Excel will close when the last outstanding reference to it is gone:

```
Application xl = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ExcelApplication);
xl.UserControl = false;
Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
ws.Name = "Monthly Expense Report";
ws.Cells[1,2] = "January";
ws.Ce......CRASH
```

Comment: What about using a little Autoit wrapper script? If your script fails then the outer Autoit script will close all excel.exe processes.

Comment: Instead of `UserControl`, can you try to set the `Visible` property to something, e.g: `xl.Visible = false` (or true if you need it visible). PS : the xl = null or xl = nothing are for most languages useless.

Comment: Have you tried `GetActiveObject` instead of opening an new instance each time?

Comment: [**GetActiveObject**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-getactiveobject) would consume an existing instance the user is using. I *need* a new instance.